# difference between preset-react and react in babel

Tags: reactjs, npm, babeljs

I am creating a React project from scratch without create-react-app.
But it worked fine on my mac but not on my other ubuntu laptop.
Below is my previous .babelrc file content.

```
"presets": [
    "@babel/preset-react",
    "@babel/preset-env"
]
```

It works fine on my mac (npm version 6.12.0) but not on ubuntu(npm version 6.14.5)
It shows error that can't compile src/index.js -> below line

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

So I changed .babelrc env file to

```
"presets": [
    "@babel/react",
    "@babel/env"
]
```

And it worked on both finally. But I am not sure exactly the difference between @babel/preset-react and @babel/react.
If anyone knows exact difference between these two, please let me know. 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can usually elide `babel-preset` in the preset name, per https://babeljs.io/docs/en/presets#preset-shorthand, but https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-react doesn't suggest that specific `@babel/preset` as an option.

Answer (score 1):

https://babeljs.io/docs/en/v7-migration#package-renames

```
{
-  "presets": ["@babel/preset-react"],
+  "presets": ["@babel/react"], // this is equivalent
-  "plugins": ["@babel/transform-runtime"],
+  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"], // same
}
```